# Why Lubin Tate character acts on torsion points of CM elliptic curve implies the group of torsion points is infinite?

Tags: elliptic-curves, group-actions, complex-multiplication

Let $F$ be quadratic imaginary field, and $R_F$ be its ring of integers.
Let $E /\Bbb{Q} $ be an elliptic curve which has CM by $F$. Suppose $E$ has good reduction at $P$,which is prime ideal of $R_F$.
Let $K$ be a completion of $F$ at $P$.

For appropriate $π \in {R_F}$,

> The action of absolute galois group $Gal( \overline{K}/ K)$ on
> $π$ torsion of $E( \overline{K})$ is given by Lubin Tate character
> associated with $π$. In particular, we see that $E(K^{LT})[π^∞]$ is infinite.
> ($K^{LT}$ denotes a compositium field of all lubin tate extension of $K$ with respect to $π$.)

Why can we conclude $E(K^{LT})[π^∞]$ is infinite from the fact that Lubin Tate character acts?

As supplementary information

$1$. I undestand 'the action is given by Lubin Tate character' means, by isomorphism $Gal(\overline{K}/ K) \cong R_K^{ \times}$, $R_K^{ \times}$ acts on torsion points, and thanks to the fact we take $π$ as an image of $P$ by a grossen character of $E$, we can say this action commutes with CM action by $R_K^{ \times}$.

$2$. Paper written by Ozeki
( https://www.sci.kanagawa-u.ac.jp/math-phys/yozeki/pdf/TorsionLT.pdf ) of the last page ($9$ page) lead me to ask this question.

Comment: First $\pi\in R_F$ not in $K$. Secondly, $E(K)$ has finite torsion. The statement in the linked paper concerns a different field, which is an infinite extension of a $p$-adic field.

Comment: @Chris Wuthrich  Thank you. I modified second typo, but I'm confused at your first concern. The linked paper reads 'By definition $K=k= \Bbb{Q}_p$', but I think this is clearly wrong, because $K$ should contain some element not in $ \Bbb{Q}_p$ because it is completion of imaginary quadratic field $F$ at a prime ideal.

Comment: $p$ splits in $K$ as $p=\pi\bar{\pi}$, so $K_{(\pi)} = \mathbb{Q}_p$. Now that you have changed to $K^{LT}$ the question becomes easy. The character acts trivially on $K^{LT}$ so the Galois group of $K^{LT}$ act trivially on $E[\pi^\infty]$.

Comment: Sorry I should have forgotten something trivial , but why can we say from   your argument that $E[ π^∞]$ is infinite ?